# On regular holonomic $D$-modules on the disk

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, d-modules

Denote by $\Delta\subset \mathbb{C}$ a small neighborhood of $0$. Let $M$ be a regular holonomic $D_\Delta$ module. In Bjork, "Analytic D-modules and applications", section 5.2, it is proven that
$$M=\oplus_{\alpha\in F} M_\alpha$$
where $F$ is a finite set of complex numbers with real part between $0$ and $1$, and $V_0(M_\alpha)$ is generated by a subspace annihilated by a power of $t\partial_t-\alpha$.

For $\alpha\not=0$, the modules $M_\alpha$ are direct sums of modules of the form $D_\Delta/(t\partial_t-\alpha)^k$. If $\alpha=0$ there is a list of various types of indecomposable objects that make up the direct summands of $M_0$.

I find the section in Bjork not so easy to understand, so I wonder if there is an alternative source for this material? Bjork refers to [this book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/algebraic-analysis/kashiwara/978-0-12-400465-8), but I do not have access to that.

Also, what I am most interested in is understand how to compute this decomposition when given a $D_\Delta$ module, for example as a quotient of a free $D_\Delta$ module.

p.s. I am aware of a perverse-sheaves perspective on this question that is written in Dimca, but I would like an exposition purely in the language of $D$-modules.